# My TextView not update

Tags: android, textview

Here is my code

this is my InstantMessage application

the method processMessage will automatically do when the applicaiton have new message

My problem is the textview not work when method processMessage do but when i send message when textview update by both use the same updateChat method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String message = text.getText().toString();
    try {
        Log.e("On Click", message + "   :   " + contact);
        chat.sendMessage(message);
        message = username + " : " + message;
        updateChat(message);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void updateChat(String message){
    chatLog += message + "\n";
    chatBox.setText(chatLog);
}

@Override
public void processMessage(org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat arg0, Message arg1) {
    String temp = InstantMessage.usernameCutter(arg0.getParticipant()) + "  :  "+ arg1.getBody();
    Log.e("ChatPage ", "ProcessMessage");
    updateChat(temp);
}
```

Comment: What is/is not happening? Do you get any errors? Be more specific

Comment: I know big fat zero about XMPP, but a quick question: is processMessage() called in the main UI thread, or from other other thread?

Comment: the textView should set it self text when the method processmessage are called but it not update by the way the method processMessage are called correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are processMessage method running on UI thread?
if not, use this construction

```
final String temp = InstantMessage.usernameCutter(arg0.getParticipant()) + "  :  "+ arg1.getBody();
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateChat(temp);
    }
});
```

Comment: UI class != UI thread. May be message processing done in other thread.

Comment: I have less known about android 

can you please explain or give me some example code please

Comment: in android all operations with UI should be done in the main thread. Just try replace code in processMessage method with my code. About threads in android: [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)